# Cannot start mysql cluster SQL node

Tags: mysql, windows, cluster-computing

I have installed a four node mysql cluster on windows:
Management Node 192.168.2.69
Data Node A 192.168.2.66
Data Node B 192.168.2.67
SQL node 192.168.2.78

I can start the first 3 without problem, but SQL node  is stuck in the following warning:

```
2017-04-07T13:55:23.970111Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2017-04-07T13:55:23.970111Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2017-04-07T13:55:23.970111Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2017-04-07T13:55:24.110707Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2017-04-07T13:55:24.127269Z 0 [Note]
2017-04-07T13:55:24.127269Z 0 [Note] NDB Index Stat: Wait for cluster to start
2017-04-07T13:55:24.127269Z 2 [Note] NDB Util: Wait for cluster to start
2017-04-07T13:55:24.127269Z 1 [Note] NDB Binlog: Check for incidents
2017-04-07T13:55:24.127269Z 0 [Note] NDB Index Stat: Started
2017-04-07T13:55:24.127269Z 2 [Note] NDB Util: Started
2017-04-07T13:55:24.127269Z 1 [Note] NDB Binlog: Wait for cluster to start
2017-04-07T13:55:24.127269Z 0 [Note] NDB Index Stat: created Ndb object 'Ndb  Index Stat', ref: 0x80070004
2017-04-07T13:55:24.141956Z 1 [Note] NDB Binlog: DISCOVER TABLE Event: REPL$mysql/ndb_schema
2017-04-07T13:55:34.513769Z 0 [Note] NDB Index Stat: execute index stats listener failed: error 1427 line 2546
2017-04-07T13:56:15.502173Z 0 [Note] NDB Index Stat: execute index stats listener failed: error 1427 line 2546
```

This repeats "NDB Index Stat: execute index stats listener failed: error 1427 line 2546"
I cannot find any help about this error. can someone help me to fix this?

**EDIT**

If I install all nodes in one server mysqld runs just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turn to be the windows firewall was on on the the data node machine 192.168.2.67, turning it off solve the problem.